# Show caller ID and number on incoming call on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, caller-id

I looked around quite a bit for an answer to this question but can't find one, so maybe I'm overlooking something obvious.

I recently starting paying my carrier for caller ID. This is great sometimes, but now when receiving calls only the caller ID name is displayed, not the caller's phone number. I can't find any setting to get the caller ID name to display along with the phone number before I answer an incoming call. This is especially difficult when the caller ID text is UNKNOWN CALLER or something similar since I can't tell if the number looks familiar before I answer.

All of this applies to receiving calls from people not in my contacts list.

Is there some way to make callers' phone numbers appear along with caller ID text when receiving incoming calls?

This is an iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 9.3.1 on T-Mobile (US) in case any of that is relevant.

Comment: Generally caller id is the carriers function, the phone is just displaying the data that was sent to it by the carrier.

Comment: Right, I'm not asking about the caller ID, I'm asking about the capability to display the phone number as well as whatever string the carrier is providing as the caller ID text.

Comment: Right, because there is no setting. The calling party data that is displayed for both name and number is just as sent by the carrier.  The exception to that being when the received number is matched to a contact, but still there are no settings.

Comment: I found this 4 years later because I want to do the same thing, show the incoming phone number alongside the contact information on the incoming call screen. It still doesn't appear to be possible on iOS 14 :(

Answer (score -2):

Unknown caller generally means their number (caller id) is private

Comment: Yeah, everyone can hide their caller id with the code #31# in front of the phone number they call.

Comment: Or else the PBX does not forward a number - or they are a scammer hiding the number

Comment: The numbers are available in the call log after I accept/reject the call, so clearly they're being transmitted as part of the call.

Answer (score -2):

As already mention in comments that is carrier function, not related or controlled by phone.

If however you need to lookup for name for unknown there are some apps that give such database, search for Block Caller, Robocall etc